# Box API java sdk creating app user

Tags: java, jwt, box

I'm fairly new to BOX api and I've a question about creating app user to be used to get files from root folder. Box.com documentation is not clear to me and I am hoping to get some answer from this forum.
  I'm able to create Enterprise access token using JWT with enterprise id but got confused with the concept of app user. Is box user created programmatically? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

An AppUser is created programmatically and you can access its content programmatically or if you're an admin, you can see its content in admin console -> content manager.

Here's some examples:
https://github.com/kendomen/BoxJavaJWTExamples

Comment: Thank you kendomen for your answer. I'm able to create app user using enterprise connection but getting "Please check the 'sub' claim" message while getting app user connection. Do you know why I'm getting that error? Also, I checked examples you provided and it is using enterprise connection to get create folder and files. When I use enterprise connection I'm not getting any folder or files. Can you tell me what I'am doing wrong?

Comment: I think the claim error has to do with this:  https://community.box.com/t5/Developer-Forum/Getting-Please-check-the-exp-claim-Exception/m-p/23843#M969

Comment: The repository is deleted. This is why you should always post snippets here so users who search later for the same answer aren't met with dead links.